# Calling draw() in draw() to increase speed

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm wondering if calling draw() in draw() is right as I've created a 10 PRINT clone in JavaScript using p5.js inspired from this: [Daniel Shiffman's Coding Challenge: 10 PRINT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bEyTZ5ZZxZs)

I tried to call draw() from draw() with an 80% probability to increase the speed and it worked. Here's my implementation:

```
var x = 0, y = 0;
var space = 10;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  background(0);
}

function draw() {
  stroke(255);
  strokeWeight(2);

  if(random() < 0.8) {
    draw();
  }

  if(random() > 0.5) {
    stroke('#F26C4D');
    line(x, y, x + space, y + space);
  }
  else {
    stroke(255);
    line(x, y + space, x + space, y);
  }

  x += space;

  if(x >= width) {
    x = 0;
    y += space;
  }
}
```

But I don't know if it's safe to do this, so it would be great if someone could suggest a method to increase its speed if this one is not safe?

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: @Cerbrus Sorry, I forgot to add that. I've added my code now

Comment: So, where is that `draw` function called?

Comment: @Cerbrus `if(random() < 0.8) {
    draw();
  }` Here

Comment: Where else? It needs to start somewhere...

Comment: @Cerbrus Its p5.js, the setup() and draw() are called automatically

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162547/discussion-between-ashar7-and-cerbrus).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is called [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)). This will work for this simple sketch, but you're going to have a couple issues:

- The framerate is not uniform. You'll notice this if you start doing animations.
- It's a little hard to follow, and will get more difficult in more advanced sketches.
- If you adjusted the probability, it's possible you would hit a stack overflow (the error, not this site).

A simpler solution would be to simply set the framerate using the `frameRate()` function.

This code would cause the `draw()` function to be called 80 times per second instead of 60:

```
function setup(){
  createCanvas(500, 500);
  frameRate(80);
}
```

More info can be found in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/frameRate).

Or if you want to play with your approach, you might think about getting rid of the recursion and extracting your drawing code into a separate function that you then call from `draw()`:

```
function draw(){
  myDrawFunction();
  if(random() < .8){
    myDrawFunction();
  }
}
```

You could then do something like loop a random number of times. But honestly your best bet is probably to just set the framerate and let P5.js do it for you.

Comment: Thanks! 
So I want to know if there is any limit for the framerate?

Comment: @Ashar7 The limit is going to depend on the device and how much work you're doing each frame. The best thing you can do is to try out different values and see what happens.